# Korn Shell Increment Date in YYYYMMDD format

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need to increment a date with the specific format YYYYMMDD (examples : 20190401 or 20190523). The 0's need to be there for single digit days and month.

I would like the input cmd line args ex ./script.ksh (# of days to increment) (starting date) or ./script.ksh (starting date) (ending date)

I made a terrible version that took in ./script.ksh (# of days) (year) (month) (day) ex: ./script.ksh 7 2019 04 10

```
#The amount of days to load by
Days=$1

Year=$2
Month=$3
Day=$4

count=0

while (($count < $Days)) 
do
    #The date of the file in format: YYYYMMDD
    if [[ $Day -eq "1" || $Day -eq "2" || $Day -eq "3" || $Day -eq "4" || $Day -eq "5" || $Day -eq "6" || $Day -eq "7" || $Day -eq "8" || $Day -eq "9" ]];
    then
        Day=0$Day
    fi

    Date=$Year$Month$Day
    print $Date

    #Check if month then day and increment accordingly

    #months with 31 days
    if [[ ($Month -eq "01" || $Month -eq "03" || $Month -eq "05" || $Month -eq "07" || $Month -eq "08" || $Month -eq "10" || $Month -eq "12") && ($Day == 31)]];
        then
                #If Dec, 31 XXXX
                if [[ $Month -eq "12" && Day == 31 ]];
                then
                        Month=01
                        Day=01
                        Year=$Year+1
                fi
                if((Day == 31));
                then
                        Month=$Month+1
                        Day=1
                fi
        #Months with 30 days
        elif [[ ($Month -eq "04" || $Month -eq "06" || $Month -eq "09" || $Month -eq "11") && ($Day == 30) ]];
        then
                if(($Day == 30));
                then
                        $Month=$Month+1
                        Day=01
                fi
        #The tricky February leap year
        elif [[ ($Month -eq "02") && ($Day == 28 || $Day == 29) ]];
        then
                leapcheck=$(($Year % 4))
                if(( leapcheck == 0 && Day == 29 ));
                then
                        Month=$Month+1
                        Day=01

                elif(( $leapcheck != 0  && $Day == 28 ));
                then
                        Month=$Month+1
                        Day=01
                fi
        else
                (( Day=$Day+1 ))
        fi

        ((count=$count+1))
done
```

which will print 20190410 till 20190416. However, there are issues with incrementing month and days where the 0 gets removed and for mine month does not increment at all. I'm sure there must be an easier and way better way than my attempt. I am new to korn shell scripting.

Comment: Do you have a version of the `date` command (such as the GNU version) that will allow you to do the job relatively painlessly?  Have you considered that option?  Failing that, can you use Perl, or another scripting language, with built-in or extension modules that make the computation easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) (with `-d` option), a simple way to do it is to convert the date to time of seconds since epoch, add the number of days in seconds and then convert it back to the format you want:

```
days=5
now=20190401

now_sec=$(date -d "${now:0:4}-${now:4:2}-${now:6:2} 11:00:00" +%s)
then_sec=$((now_sec + days * 3600 * 24))
then=$(date -d @"$then_sec" +%Y%m%d)

echo "$then" # will output 20190406
```

The `${now:0:4}` extracts part of the string, see [parameter expansions](http://cdesktopenv.sourceforge.net/man1/ksh.html#sect12).